# Does the IKImageView imageCorrection property work?

Tags: cocoa, cifilter, ikimageview

IKImageView offers an 'imageCorrection' property, which takes a CIFilter and, presumably, uses it when displaying the image.

When I tried using it recently, it didn't work for me. When I set the property to a new CIFilter instance, it remains nil.

Has anyone managed to use this successfully?

Answer (score 0):

> When I tried using it recently, it didn't work for me. When I set the property to a new CIFilter instance, it remains nil.

You probably didn't hook up your outlet to your image view, so the pointer in your outlet is `nil`, so you sent your `setImageCorrection:` message (whether implicit or explicit) to `nil`.

Comment: Nope. It's connected. I've been doing IB since 1991. :)

Comment: Also, I could see the IKImageView outlet's value in gdb, etc.